# Android Eclipse Error: Logcat continuously receiving "MPL-FIFO error"

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, fifo

Here is snippet of the ever-increasing Logcat logs:

```
07-09 20:26:30.530: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:30.571: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:30.621: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:30.651: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:30.691: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:30.711: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:30.721: D/AutoSetting(514): service - mHandler: update timezone
07-09 20:26:30.721: D/AutoSetting(514): service - getTimeZoneIDFromMCC() MCC code: 466 TimeZoneID: Asia/Taipei
07-09 20:26:30.721: D/AutoSetting(514): service - setSystemTimeZoneID() TimeZoneID is not changed, current: Asia/Taipei
07-09 20:26:30.761: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:30.791: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:30.831: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:30.871: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:30.911: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:30.951: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:30.991: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.031: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.071: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.111: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.151: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.191: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.211: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.251: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.291: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.311: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.351: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.391: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.431: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.471: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.511: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.551: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.592: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.612: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.652: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.692: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.712: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.752: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.792: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.812: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.852: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.892: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.932: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:31.972: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.012: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.052: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.092: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.122: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.152: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.192: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.212: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.252: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.292: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.322: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.352: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.382: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.412: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.452: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.502: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.532: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.572: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.603: I/TelephonyRegistry(272): notifyServiceState: 0 home Far EasTone (N/A) 46601  0 UMTS CSS not supported -1 -1RoamInd: -1DefRoamInd: -1EriInd: -1EriMode: -1RadioPowerSv: falseEmergOnly: false
07-09 20:26:32.613: I/TelephonyRegistry(272): notifyDataConnection: state=2 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=null interfaceName=rmnet0 networkType=3
07-09 20:26:32.613: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.623: D/TelephonyRegistry(272): notifyDataConnection() state=2isDataConnectivityPossible()true, reason=null
07-09 20:26:32.623: D/TelephonyRegistry(272): broadcastDataConnectionStateChanged()  state=CONNECTEDtypes=default,hipri,dun,supl, interfaceName=rmnet0, apn=internet
07-09 20:26:32.623: D/StatusBarPolicy(373): onDataConnectionStateChanged , state= 2, networkType= 3
07-09 20:26:32.623: D/StatusBarPolicy(373): mPhoneState = 0
07-09 20:26:32.623: D/StatusBarPolicy(373): onDataConnectionStateChanged , SystemProperties.get("net.gprs.data.connected")= 1
07-09 20:26:32.643: D/PendingMsgSendReceiverRegister(818): Enter sendQueuedMessage
07-09 20:26:32.653: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.663: D/AutoSetting(514): receiver - intent: android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE
07-09 20:26:32.663: D/AutoSetting(514): receiver - flag: Service state 0
07-09 20:26:32.663: W/System.err(514): android.provider.Settings$SettingNotFoundException: monitor_my_location_enabled
07-09 20:26:32.663: W/System.err(514):  at android.provider.Settings$System.getBoolean(Settings.java:962)
07-09 20:26:32.663: W/System.err(514):  at com.htc.htclocationservice.AutoSettingReceiver.startPhoneStateMonitorServiceIfEnabled(AutoSettingReceiver.java:187)
07-09 20:26:32.663: W/System.err(514):  at com.htc.htclocationservice.AutoSettingReceiver$Process.run(AutoSettingReceiver.java:162)
07-09 20:26:32.663: D/PendingMsgSendReceiverRegister(818): New state: 0
07-09 20:26:32.663: D/PendingMsgSendReceiverRegister(818): state in service
07-09 20:26:32.663: D/PendingMsgSendReceiverRegister(818): send HANDLER_SEND_QUEUED_MSG to mWorkingHandler
07-09 20:26:32.673: D/AutoSetting(514): service - onStartCommand() action: com.htc.app.autosetting.timezoneupdate
07-09 20:26:32.683: D/AutoSetting(514): service - onStartCommand() Service state: 0
07-09 20:26:32.693: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.723: D/MobileDataStateTracker(272): replacing old mInterfaceName (rmnet0) with rmnet0 for supl
07-09 20:26:32.723: D/MobileDataStateTracker(272): replacing old mInterfaceName (rmnet0) with rmnet0 for dun
07-09 20:26:32.723: D/MobileDataStateTracker(272): replacing old mInterfaceName (rmnet0) with rmnet0 for hipri
07-09 20:26:32.733: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.743: D/PendingMsgSendReceiverRegister(818): sendQueuedMessage, cursor not null and count: 0
07-09 20:26:32.783: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.813: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.863: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.893: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.933: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:32.973: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.013: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.063: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.093: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.133: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.173: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.213: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.253: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.293: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.313: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.353: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.393: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.433: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.473: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.513: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.553: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.593: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.634: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.674: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.714: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.764: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.794: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.814: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.854: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.894: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.934: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:33.974: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.014: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.054: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.094: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.114: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.154: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.194: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.214: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.254: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.294: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.334: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.374: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.414: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.454: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.494: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.534: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.564: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.594: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.634: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.675: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.715: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.755: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.795: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.835: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.875: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.915: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.955: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:34.995: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.035: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.075: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.115: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.155: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.195: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.235: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.275: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.315: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.355: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.385: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.415: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.455: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.495: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.535: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.565: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.595: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.635: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.665: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.696: D/AutoSetting(514): service - mHandler: update timezone
07-09 20:26:35.696: D/AutoSetting(514): service - getTimeZoneIDFromMCC() MCC code: 466 TimeZoneID: Asia/Taipei
07-09 20:26:35.696: D/AutoSetting(514): service - setSystemTimeZoneID() TimeZoneID is not changed, current: Asia/Taipei
07-09 20:26:35.706: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.736: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.766: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.796: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.836: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.876: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.916: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.956: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:35.996: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.016: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.056: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.096: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.116: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.156: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.196: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.216: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.256: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.296: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.336: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.376: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.416: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.456: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.496: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.516: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.556: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.596: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.636: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.676: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.717: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.767: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.797: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.817: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.857: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.897: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.937: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:36.977: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:37.017: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:37.057: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:37.097: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:37.137: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:37.177: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:37.217: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:37.247: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:37.287: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:37.307: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:37.347: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
07-09 20:26:37.387: E/MPL-fifo(272): device/htc/common/invensense/mlsdk/mllite/mlFIFO.c|FIFOGetAccelFloat|1672 returning 3
```

The only thing I can tell from the logs, is that the messages appear very quickly. There's no short breaks whatsoever in between these red log messages. (Differences between each interval are less than 100 milliseconds).

Here's how I triggered all these log messages:

1. Run Eclipse IDE.
2. While Eclipse is loading, plug Android plone into laptop with USB wire.
3. While Eclipse is loading, toggle on "USB Debugging connected" from OFF to ON via Android Settings.
4. Wait until Eclipse finishes. Then watch the Logcat DDMS.

These Logcat messages do not affect Android phone, but they do affect the performances on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The main problem it was causing these Logcat error log messages is because of the Live Wallpaper.

The specific Live Wallpaper is Maps, which, I think, is one of the default selections of Live Wallpapers in an HTC Android phone. When this Live Wallpaper is applied, it will continuously send out packages asking for GPS locations. If it's unable to receive packages, it will blip out these log messages.

I do not know how to file a ticket for this. I'm just going to set a different Live Wallpaper.

EDIT:

Setting a different Live Wallpaper fixes the problem. Therefore the main problem has to be the Maps Live Wallpaper. This issue is **NOT resolved**, but was given a workaround. Those who happened to encounter similar problems, please check to see if it's the Map Live Wallpaper setting it off.